BibLaTeX, APA and French: still american date display
I'm having an issue with using BibLaTeX and the APA bibliographic format in French (using up to date biblatex-apa and french-apa.lbx), and I can't find the necessary information to fix it: when I insert a reference to a website (@online) in the bibliography, the access date is ordered month day, year (as in American English), whereas in French it should be day month year.
I have configured the French language with polyglossia (but I've also tried with babel), and I've done the mapping for french-apa. I also tried to add the datetime2 in the preamble, with no luck.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @online{enssib_index_,
   title = {Index thématique | Enssib},
   author = {{Enssib}},
   url = {https://www.enssib.fr/bibliotheque-numerique/index-thematique},
   urldate = {2024-11-15},
   langid = {french},
   organization = {Enssib | École nationale supérieure des sciences de l'information et des bibliothèques},
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
% \usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
 
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
 
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  natbib=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
 
\begin{document}
 
\Today{} \citep{enssib_index_}
 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}

The display of the bibliographic reference is (note the correct French "novembre"):

It seems there is something beyond my LaTeX skills that I need to do.
Could anyone please give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?
EDIT: It is known that Biblatex offers different options to format a date, using \DeclareFieldFormat for fields such as urldate, date...
Nevertheless, this ad hoc solution alters the normal behaviour of APA formatting and the display (using biblatex-apa) of the date in French, across all French-speaking countries. The aim here, therefore, is to find a way to achieve a standard display for French (via french-apa.lbx - whom it is the aim).

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your proposed solution. However, this amounts to cobbling together a desired display, whereas the intended result is perfectly standard in French, which is precisely the purpose of biblatex-apa and french-apa.lbx.

If your aim is to get the style adjusted, you should bring this up at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues?q=is%3Aissue+
